# Python, host webpage streaming video

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, picamera

I have a raspberry pi and picamera.  I want to set it up to stream video to a webpage that can be accessed over the internet.  I already have coded it to work on my local network, but that's not the ultimate goal.  Can you help or point me toward some resources I can use to help build this project?  There's so many different walkthroughs online so I haven't figured out which one is actually what I need.
Code's below, in addition to the picamera, I do have buttons hooked up to start/stop the stream (can be seen in the code).

```
import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server
from gpiozero import Button

PAGE="""\
<html>
<head>
<title>picamera Shadows Of Brimestone streaming</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><p style="font-family:Brush Script MT" font size = "8" >Shadows Of BrimeStone Stream</p></h1>
<img src="stream.mjpg" width="1350" height="620" />
</body>
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

    
button1 = Button(17)#17 for green button
button2 = Button(27)#27 for red button


with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='1350x620', framerate=12) as camera:
    output = StreamingOutput()
    def green_Button(): #starts the show
        camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
    def red_Button(): #temporarily stops the show
        camera.stop_recording()
        
    button1.when_pressed = green_Button
    button2.when_pressed = red_Button
    
    try:
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()

    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()
```

Comment: Do you want to, like, stream it to a remote source, like a relay, and then have people watch the stream without being directly connected to your machine?

Comment: Yes, I want to stream a simple video to friends in other locations.